# param is missing or the value is empty error with nested model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I hope I am not asking an obvious question/ wont get down voted to hell for this.I am working on rails app and I am getting a "param is missing or the value is empty" error.

I have an event and questions that have already been created and I am using a nested form to allow the user to answer all the questions at once.

I am using rails 4

Models

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :questions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :event

   has_many :answers
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :question

end
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'home#index'

devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}, controllers:           {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}

resources :answers
resources :users, only: [:new, :create]

resources :questions do
   resources :answers #-> domain.com/questions/1/answers/new
end

resources :events, only: [:index, :new, :show, :update] do
   patch ":id", action: :index
   collection do
       get :favorite
       get "question/:id", action: :question
   end
end

get 'users/new', to: 'users#new'
post 'users/new', to: 'users#create'
get 'events/favorite', to: 'events#favorite', via:[:get], as: 'favorite'
post 'events/:id' => 'events#update'
get 'answers/new' => 'answers#new'
get 'events/question' => 'events#question'

end
```

answers controller

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
def new
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @answer = Answer.new
end

def show

end

def create
    @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
    @answer.save
    redirect_to events_path, notice: "Answered Questions"
end

private
    def answer_params
       params.require(:answer).permit(:response, :question, :event, :user, :event_id, :question_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

This is where my issue lies. Originally I had a very generic nested from a la http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised but I switched the form_for down to the @answer because that is whats being created and switched to a button_to because the submit button was not writing the answer to the DB.(I believe it was trying to trigger something with @event )

```
<h1>New answers</h1>

<%= fields_for @event do |f| %>  
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
    <%= f.fields_for :questions do |b| %>
  <p>
        <%= b.text_field :poll%><br />
            <%= form_for @answer do |x| %>      
                <%= x.text_field :response %>
            <% end %>
   </p>
  <% end %>
  <%= button_to "New", action: "create"%>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', answers_path %>
```

Please let me know if you need anymore code or have any questions

Thanks!

UPDATE

I have reworked my code based off this blog post http://iroller.ru/blog/2013/10/14/nested-model-form-in-rails-4/

now I am running the update through the events controller or at least I'm trying to.
The code is as follows, the error im getting now is

undefined local variable or method `event_params' for #

Thanks guys and girls sorry for the dumb questions

Models

```
 class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :questions
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
  end

  class Question < ActiveRecord::Base 
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :event
   has_many :answers
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
  end

  class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :question
  end
```

Routes.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'

  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}, controllers:        {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}

   resources :answers
   resources :users, only: [:new, :create]

   resources :questions do
     resources :answers #-> domain.com/questions/1/answers/new
   end

   resources :events, only: [:index, :new, :show, :update] do
     patch ":id", action: :index
     collection do
     get :favorite
     get "question/:id", action: :question
   end
  end

  get 'users/new', to: 'users#new'
  post 'users/new', to: 'users#create'
  get 'events/favorite', to: 'events#favorite', via:[:get], as: 'favorite'
  post 'events/:id' => 'events#update'
  get 'answers/new' => 'answers#new'
  get 'events/question' => 'events#question'
 end
```

methods from events_controller

```
 def question
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])
 end 


 def update
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])

 if @event.update(event_params)
    redirect_to events_path, notice: "Answers saved"
  else
    redirect_to events_question_path, notice: "Answers not saved"
 end
```

questions.erb

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@event) do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>
   <%= f.object.name %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :questions, f.object.questions do |q| %>
    <%= q.object.poll%>
  <%= q.simple_fields_for :answers, q.object.answers.build do |a|%>
    <%= a.text_field :response %>
  <% end %>
 <%end %>
 <%= f.button :submit%>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Why you did not use `form_for` for @event and `b.fields_for` for @answer? I think your problem is because structure of your form.

Comment: @KienThanh when I do that it runs update in the events controller and wont save the answer. Do you know how I could save the multiple new answers through update in the events_controller?

Comment: you should take a look at this screen cast [Nested model form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised)

Comment: @KienThanh I have, such a great series.